# Graph API v1.0 from Facebook-PHP-SDK v4

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have Facebook-PHP-SDK v4 and Facebook-JavaScript-SDK. User authenticates via JS and I work with his access token via PHP.

I'd like to call Graph API v1.0, but when I try to specify version in FacebookRequest I get the same error as I did calling APIv2. I tried to specify version in JS block but it did not help with my problem, I still get:

> The global ID  is not allowed. Please use the
>   application specific ID instead

How can I fix it? I know that API v1.0 will be unavailable soon but now I'm looking for a temporary and fast solution.

Here is Javascript Init Request:

```
FB.init({
        appId      : document.getElementById("facebook_appid").value,
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server use the cookies
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v1.0' // use version 1.0
    });

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response); //show login status
});
```

And this is PHP block with the request:

```php
/**
 * Use long-live access token
 **/
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appid, $secret);
if (empty($extended_user_access_token)) {
    $session = new FacebookSession($user_access_token);
    $session = $session->getLongLivedSession();
    $extended_user_access_token = $session->getToken();
} else {
    $session = new FacebookSession($extended_user_access_token);
}

/**
 * Validate facebook session
 **/
try {
    $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

/**
 * Call user by global id
 **/
if ($session) {
    try {
        $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $session,
            'GET',
            '/<my-global-id>',
            null,
            'v1.0'
        );

        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "Exception code: " . $ex->getCode();
        echo ", with message: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you actually getting the user id? is it hardcoded?

Comment: Right now - yes, I used [graph.facebook.com](http://graph.facebook.com) to find it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter if you add the v1.0 tag to your call, if the App was created after end of April 2014 it will not be able to use v1.0 and you will only be able to use App Scoped IDs.

That is why the global ID does not work, use FB.login to authorize the User and use the gained (App Scoped) ID for the call.